# Cannot parse date in Firefox that can be parsed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, date-parsing

I have a set of dates like `June 2017`, `October 2016`, et cetera.

In Firefox, doing `new Date('June 2017')` triggers an `Invalid Date` error. The same works just fine in Chrome.

I tried using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) but the result is the same.

How can I let it work properly?

Here is a [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVwbxJ) to test quickly, and the same as a snippet (check your browser console):

```js
var date = 'June 2017';
var formatDate = new Date(date);

console.log(formatDate);
```

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), especially about `dateString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed differences between browsers. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

If your strings are always of the form `Month Year`, you could consider parsing it as follows.

```js
function parseDateString(str) {
  let months = ['January', 'February', 'March',
        'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  let split = str.split(/\s+/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(parseInt(split[1], 10), months.indexOf(split[0])));
}

function test(str) {
  console.log(`"${str}" is parsed as`, parseDateString(str));
}

test('June 2017');
test('October 2016');
test('March 2018');
```